# Given an element in colname, I need to find the corresponding element in another colname

Tags: get, grep

I want to figure out how to obtain all the elements from an entire row from a matrix when I'm given an element in a matrix.

In my case, I have a matrix that's already a dataset, with a set amount of rows and columns. The Columns are categories defining the elements for each row.

As an illustration:

```
colnames(data.set) "GOID" "TERM" "ONTOLOGY" "DEFINITION"
```

I was given an element "response to heat", which is under "TERM" colname, and I have to find the responding element in the "GOID" colnam.

Comment: can you paste some sample data, and tell what would be your expected output?

Comment: GOID TERM ONTOLOGY DEFINITION
x1    x2    x3        x4
y1    y2    y3        y4
z1    z2    z3        z4
..    ..    ..        ..

For example, I am given y2 and I want to find y1. 
Another way to put it is if I were to get the entire output for row y.
This is in R, btw.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a job for awk:

```
awk '$2=="response to heat"{print $1}' file
```

Note that without your input example, the above line may not work for your real data (different FS for example). but you got the idea.

Comment: GOID TERM ONTOLOGY DEFINITION
x1    x2    x3        x4
y1    y2    y3        y4
z1    z2    z3        z4
..    ..    ..        ..

For example, I am given y2 and I want to find y1. 
Another way to put it is if I were to get the entire output for row y.
This is in R, btw.